# Multiple Countdowns Not Showing Correctly After 1 Completes

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a website where I need 3 countdowns.  Everything is perfectly fine while all 3 countdowns are running, however, once one is completed, the page only shows 2 of the countdowns and not 3.  I would like all 3 countdowns to still be shown with ('XX Completed') being the text - XX being the countdown title.  Below is the code I have so far:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
<h2 style="font-weight: bold" id="countdownQuali"></h2>
<h2 style="font-weight: bold" id="countdownSprint"></h2>
<h2 style="font-weight: bold" id="countdownRace"></h2>

<script>

    var countDownQuali = new Date('22 Apr, 2022 19:00 GMT+0400').getTime();
    function calculateQualiCountdown() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownQuali - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    document.getElementById('countdownQuali').innerHTML =
    'Qualifying Starts In ' + days + ' Days ' + hours + ' Hours';
    if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById('countdownQuali').innerHTML =
    'Qualifying Completed';
    }
    }
    var x = setInterval(calculateQualiCountdown, 1000);
    
    var countDownSprint = new Date('23 Apr, 2022 18:30 GMT+0400').getTime();
    function calculateSprintCountdown() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownSprint - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    document.getElementById('countdownSprint').innerHTML =
    'Sprint Starts In ' + days + ' Days ' + hours + ' Hours';
    if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById('countdownSprint').innerHTML =
    'Sprint Completed';
    }
    }
    var x = setInterval(calculateSprintCountdown, 1000);
    
    var countDownRace = new Date('24 Apr, 2022 17:00 GMT+0400').getTime();
    function calculateRaceCountdown() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownRace - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    document.getElementById('countdownRace').innerHTML =
    'Race Starts In ' + days + ' Days ' + hours + ' Hours';
    if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById('countdownRace').innerHTML =
    'Race Completed';
    }
    }
    var x = setInterval(calculateRaceCountdown, 1000);
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Any help on this would be great!  Thanks

Comment: Please format and indent your code. It's pretty hard to read.

Comment: From my side it's all formatted - apologies